# Send files via Apollo Client and receive in Graphene Flask server

Tags: apollo-client, graphene-python

I'm using Graphene package in my Flask app (https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene) and graphene-file-upload (https://pypi.org/project/graphene-file-upload/). I need to receive a file through a mutation as bellow:

```
class Picture(graphene.Mutation):
    class Arguments:
        file = Upload(required=True)

    numerical_id = graphene.Int()

    def mutate(self, info, file):
    ... continues

class Mutations(graphene.ObjectType):

    picture = Picture.Field()
```

But when I send the mutation via an Apollo client (https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/) I'm receving this errors:

```
Unknown type "Upload". Perhaps you meant "Float"?
Cannot query field "picture" on type "Mutations".
```

Is there any workaround for it? Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you import Upload from graphene_file_upload.scalars? You also need to make sure you fix the view function you hook up to your /graphql view

Comment: Thanks ryan! The graphql view was exacly my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a couple of hours trying to figure this out since the mutation worked fine via Postman but not when sent from the Frontend.
The problem was that the parent component was using a different `ApolloProvider` from the one I was expecting.